# Product image not coming in mobile view in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-page, mobile-device

I am not able to find out what is the issue. Product Image aren't display on the product page in mobile view.

How to solve this.

Comment: please check console log and what error happen please share this.

Comment: no error in console

Comment: product name in any special charecter " , ' , @ ?

Comment: no after removing bootstrap cdn Its coming proper in mobile view so how i remove cdn from particular page. or any other solution because cdn is required

Comment: i removed but its affect to other css is any other solution ?